# Does hash-then-sign provide confidentiality?

Tags: signature

Suppose I use the hash-and-sign paradigm and reveal a signature on the message digest $\sigma(H(m))$. Would just revealing this signature violate message confidentiality (assuming H is one-way and collision resistant)?

Comment: It seems that you are asking for your HW. While we only provide hints to those, we first want to see what you tried. Could you [edit] your Qs and show your progress?

Comment: Since this looks like homework, I'll only provide a hint: assume it's known by adversaries that $m$ is one of $m_0$ or $m_1\ne m_0$ (which fits the framework of a CPA attack against confidentiality).